# Protecting React Routes by Remote Role Based Authorisation

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a HOC for protecting routes of my Client Side React application. The idea is to allow a remote api to verify a user's token and based on a set of rules authorize the user to view the route.

This means per each route visit, there will an AJAX request to authorize a user token against the rules of a particular route.

Can this approach be considered a worthless one given that all the code is in the client side and making API calls for this kind of an authorisation just might be overkill?

Comment: How dynamic is the ROLE verification? I may be a bit of overkill. Can the app just pull role access data periodically and simply conditionally render routes and/or do a role check when trying to match a route?

Comment: My idea was to check role when trying to match a route, but the checking will be handled entirely in the server.

Comment: TBH seems like a terrible UX to check a user's role(s) on every route access. A better experience may be to trust the token for route access and send it along with all requests to the back end API, if an invalid token is detected then return a 401/403 error back to the UI and handle accordingly. Just an opinion and I don't know what your full use-case is.